# Problem checking for network connectivity

Tags: android, networking, connectivity

I have an IntentService which makes some web service calls.  Before making these calls I check to make sure the device has network connectivity.  I am doing so like this:

```
 private boolean isOnline() {
  ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  return connec.getNetworkInfo(0).isConnectedOrConnecting();
 }
```

Unfortunately, when I'm debugging on my Android device, this returns false when I have both a network and a wireless connection.

Some interesting tidbits about connec.getNetworkInfo(0):

```
mIsAvailable = true
mNetworkType = 0
mTypeName = "mobile"
mState.name = "DISCONNECTED"
```

Clearly this code is not sufficient (perhaps it would only return true if I sent some bit over the network and turned the radio on?).  Moreover, since I'm not well versed in the ConnectivityManager, I'm assuming I should probably be scanning all networks (ie: getNetworkInfo(0 through N)).

How can I properly accomplish what I'm wanting here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo network = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(network != null){
        return network.isAvailable();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ya this will work.  I found this, but had not updated this post yet.  Thank you

Comment: And also add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> permission to manifest